# JMeter-For each implementation

Tags: jmeter

I have an API which takes multiple IDs as a parameter:

```
http://pqa-volpqa.unknown.com:8080/items/batch/?Ids=00000017072571,00000017072588,00000017072595,00000019786230,00000019987460,00000019988238,00000019988283,00000019990170,00000020015206,00000020015213
```

Now these IDs are mention in a CSV file like below:

```
00000017072571
00000017072588
00000017072595
00000019786230
~~
~~
~~
00000020015213
```

How can I implement this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a [Loop controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Loop_Controller) with **Loop count** = number of IDs you want to add. Then add a [Counter](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Counter) inside the loop controller with the below configurations:

- **Start:** `1`
- **Increment:** `1`
- **Reference Name:** `Counter`
- Check the boxes for `Track counter independently for each user` and `Reset counter on each thread group iteration`

Add a [CSV Data Set Config](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) after the counter with the below configurations:

- **Filename :** `The full name to your file` // if the csv file is not in the same folder with your jmx file you should enter the full path to your CSV file.
- **Variable Names :** id

Finally, add a [BeanShell Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_Sampler) after the csv data set config with the below code in the code area:

```
String id = vars.get("id");
int Counter = Integer.parseInt(vars.get("Counter"));
if (Counter == 1){
    vars.put("IDs", id);
}
else{
    vars.put("IDs", vars.get("IDs") + "," + id);
}
```

All of the above should be before your API, now you can use your API as below:

```
http://pqa-volpqa.unknown.com:8080/items/batch/?Ids=${IDs}
```

Comment: Thanks for help ,but i want to increment value from CSV on each occurrence rather than each iteration ,how to do that ?

Comment: Are you calling the same API more than once in the same iteration? if thats the case, you can copy the above loop controller and paste it just before your HTTP sampler.

Answer (score 1):

1. If they are as a single string in CSV file you can just use [__StringFromFile()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__StringFromFile) or [__FileToString()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__FileToString) function to read them directly into request parameter
2. If they are each one a separate line it is still possible with [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) like:

   ```
   ${__groovy(def line = new File('/path/to/your/file.csv').getText().replaceAll(System.getProperty('line.separator')\,'\,'),)}
   ```

See [Apache JMeter Functions - An Introduction](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-functions-introduction) to learn more about JMeter Functions concept.